# How to start/install/access Activiti Explorer on Apache ServiceMix 4.5.3?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, activiti, apache-servicemix

I'm new to Activiti/Apache ServiceMix and I'm a bit lost on how to access the Activiti Explorer.

I have installed Activiti via Karaf (feature:install activiti) but how could I access the Explorer Web UI?

I have tried using localhost:8181/activiti-explorer URL but it gives me a 404 error.

I can access the karaf web console so I know for sure that Servicemix and Karaf are up and running. Also, Activiti reports to be installed and running.

Thank you

Comment: Is Activiti-Explorer really deployed? I think part it's not installed with `feature:install activiti`, but I'm not a service mix user. If you want Activit-explorer, install war support in Service Mix and download a complete Activiti distro (same version) and desploy the activiti-explorer war.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Activiti means installing the activiti **engine**.

The engine has no web component, yo need to install a diferent component called *activiti-explorer*. Sadly it has no suport by now, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SMX4-1623 .